# How To hide application icon from my launcher android

Tags: android, launcher

I m newbie in android i created Simple launcher from Tutorial
i am showing all app in listview appdetails(app lable ,icon,package)

I want Hide app Icon Which I Want ..

i am trying To Hide 
but I am Unable To Understande How To Getcomponent Name Of Other application

```
private void addClickListener() {
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos,
                long id) {

            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(apps.get(pos).name.toString());, apps.get(pos).name.toString());.LauncherActivity);
         manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            /*Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(apps.get(pos).name.toString());
            AppsListActivity.this.startActivity(i);*/
        }
    });
```

here is code Which I Tried but Not Working

plzz tell me what i am doing wrong and what should i do

please thanx advance

EDit

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ah.hathi.simplelauncher"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<activity
android:name="ah.hathi.simplelauncher.HomeActivity"
android:label="Simple Launcher Home"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:stateNotNeeded="true"
>
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

```
<activity
android:name="ah.hathi.simplelauncher.AppsListActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
>
```

Comment: Its your custom launcher ?

Comment: if yes then on item click you have the position of item simply  inflate the imageview of appicon and setvisibility  gone or invisible

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi yes its a custome launcher , its a listview Of All App Dtails...i want to  Hide  App From Listview ...

i have to create checkbox In Listview

Comment: use this line on onitemClick  ImageView_image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);                                            _image.stevisibility(View.Invisible)

Comment: are u getting my point ?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable a component via `PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting()`, which will have the effect of removing it from the Launcher.

**List component names in Android:**

Following is the code to get the list of activities/applications installed on Android

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List packageList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

You can get the component names from packageList.

[**ComponentName**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html):

> Identifier for a specific application component (`Activity`, `Service`,
>   `BroadcastReceiver`, or `ContentProvider`) that is available. Two pieces
>   of information, encapsulated here, are required to identify a
>   component: the package (a String) it exists in, and the class (a
>   String) name inside of that package.

set permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE>
```

From [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE):

> Allows an application to change whether an application component
>   (other than its own) is enabled or not.
>
> Note: Not for use by third-party applications.

Comment: Can U Give A Brief Explanation ..So That I implement

manager is PackageManager In code

Comment: how to get Componentname of Other app

Comment: can you tell me what is component name of application (like)

Comment: i already set the permission as you decribed but i got the security issues:
01-20 12:15:29.671: E/AndroidRuntime(742): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=742, uid=10088, package uid=10097 –

Comment: @user3825086 can you post your manifest. and note the above permission is not for use by third-party applications.

Comment: Check My Edit I hv Posted Menifest

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Or try this:

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("com.google.android.talk",
    "com.google.android.talk.LAUNCHER"),
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Note: The icon may not be gone until the next reboot.
So reboot your device and see the applied effect!

Comment: Sir
getComponentName(); how to get componentname of other name

Comment: if i use getcomponentname(); it will not hide other app which i selected

Comment: i have tried but i got this error when i click ...
01-20 12:15:29.671: E/AndroidRuntime(742): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=742, uid=10088, package uid=10097